# What does COM exception 80010108 mean?

Tags: c#, com, powerpoint

I am trying to create a PowerPoint presentation from inside a C# .NET application.

For the most part it is working, but every once in a while I am seeing this error in my logs:

```
Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID
{91493441-5A91-11CF-8700-00AA0060263B} from the IClassFactory failed due
to the following error: 80010108.
```

The line that triggers this exception is:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.ApplicationClass oPPT =
         new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.ApplicationClass();
```

Does anyone know what this means and how I can avoid it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error code represents the error RPC_E_DISCONNECTED.  There are many reasons this particular error code can occur and we'd need a bit more information to understand what's going on.

If you have any more data plug it into google with RPC_E_DISCONNECTED and you'll likely get a lot of results.  There appear to be a lot of articles related to office, managed code and RPC_E_DISCONNECTED

Answer (score 2):

The error message means: "The object invoked has disconnected from its clients".

Try creating the object using

```
    ApplicationClass oPPT = (ApplicationClass)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(ApplicationClass));
```